# Best way to prevent plugins being shared amongst users

Tags: c#, plugins, mef, plugin-architecture

We are developing an C# application based on a plugin architecture using MEF.

The main application is just a basic framework and it's modularized functionality will be provided by plugins that the user will have to purchase.

I don't really want to have separate licence keys for each plugin, but do need to take reasonable precautions so that the user does not just buy one copy of a plugin and then install it in a dozen instances of the application.

Comment: Authentication server?

Comment: Possible, but quite a few installations will either not have Internet or will have the connection blocked.